# Is it possible to get b2c access token with multiple values in "aud" claim so that the same token used at multiple APIs?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I was able to get an access token from b2c after registering the API-1 and Test client application in azure portal and by following the documentation at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens and other related documentation.

This token contains "aud" with single client id of the API-1 because the that is what the token in intended for. So far so good.

Next I would like to get an access token that I would like to use at API-1, API-2 and API-3 (each API is registered as different client/application with b2c). Fortunately all of these APIs use the same authorization server. This would allow each of the APIs to check incoming access token (from my test application) for its client id in the "aud" field.

The open id spec (https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) says that this should be possible for "aud" as shown below:

***aud**
REQUIRED. Audience(s) that this ID Token is intended for. It MUST contain the OAuth 2.0 client_id of the Relying Party as an audience value. It MAY also contain identifiers for other audiences. **In the general case, the aud value is an array of case sensitive strings**. In the common special case when there is one audience, the aud value MAY be a single case sensitive*

But I have no idea about how to configure b2c or my client code so that I can get an access token that has all 3 client ids in the "aud" field, indicating it can be used in of these 3 apis. I could not find any information on how to make this work with b2c.

Any links or documentation and a brief discussion of how I can make this work would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.

You can't get a access token with multiple values in the `aud` claim. In fact, you can't configure it like this, it's **not supported**! When you try to place multiple api resources in the scope, you will not be able to obtain an access token. The expected result will be an error:

> AADB2C90146: The scope
> ' API-1, API-2...'
> provided in request specifies more than one resource for an access
> token, which is not supported.

A token can only correspond to one resources. The access token is issued according to the [api audience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) you want to access, and it is unique! A token can only have one `audience`, and you cannot use multiple scopes to request access tokens.